How do you prove mathematical induction without the notion of a set?
EDIT - Peano's axioms for N can't be used to answer this question, because they assume induction.  So what axioms can be used?  I am thinking the following:
P1. x ∈ N iff x=1 ∨ ∃y (x=y' ∧ y ∈ N)
P2. 0'=1 ∧ 0 ∉ N
P3. If x'=y' then x=y

In most books on mathematics, they state the principle of weak mathematical induction without proof.  I have a book on logic, which proves weak and strong induction using the notion of infinity, and I have a book on Axiomatic Set Theory that derived weak induction using the notion of sets.  My question is, how do you prove the principle of mathematical induction, without the notions of set, and infinity?
Principle of Mathematical Induction
Let n denote an arbitrary natural number.
Let N denote the set of natural numbers.
P(1) and if P(n) then P(n+1); therefore
∀m ∈ N[P(m)]
Proof.
The principle is straightforward to prove if you have the notion of infinity.
From if P(n) then P(n+1), you get an infinite sequence of true propositions:
If P(1) then P(2), if P(2) then P(3),...
Then by an infinite number of modus ponens arguments you get the following sequence of true propositions:
P(1), P(2), P(3),...
Then by repeated conjunction arguments you get the following true proposition:
P(1) and P(2) and P(3) and...
Which means ∀m ∈ N[P(m)].
The proof of the principle using the notion of set in my book on Axiomatic Set Theory, is quite unintuitive.  So I'm looking for a proof/derivation that uses first order logic, but doesn't use the notions of set and infinity.

You can prove it in set theory, type theory, second-order logic. All them have stronger principles that first-order logic dos not have.

In order to obtain the principle of induction, you need equivalent or stronger mathematical principles. It is possible to obtain induction from an axiom known as Hume’s principle, and there is a school of thought (Logicism) that argues that this principle is purely logical and not mathematical.

Your proof implicitly uses mathematical induction to prove mathematical induction.

And, in any case, this is yet another example of you using this forum as a way to get people to discuss your own ideas. That is an improper use of the site. Please stop. There are plenty of philosophy sites that allow for open discussion. This is not one of them.

I don't understand your question. The principle of induction as you stated it, uses the notion of set and infinity. How as any theory without a notion of set and infinity supposed to prove it? Even just stating the principle uses the notions which you want to exclude. Maybe, you can rephrase the principle to some context you have in mind which isn't talking about sets or infinity?

@MichaelCarey, I simply want to avoid the set theoretic proof.  That's what I meant by don't use sets in the proof.  To state the axiom you need the elementhood symbol, but not more.  And the notion of infinity is not required to state the principle.  You will need the assumption let k denote an arbitrary natural number.  But that doesn't necessitate the notion of set

The proposed proof, in your post is also a bit strange. It uses an infinitely long proof, - infinitely many modus ponens arguments. Proofs are typically required to be finite.

@MichaelCarey, the proof is not mine.  I regard it as a heuristic argument, that's why I'm seeking a rigorous one.

Within Peano Arithmetic, the axiom schema of induction is, as the name suggests, an axiom, which is not provable from the other axioms.  In stronger axiomatic systems such as Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, one can prove induction or more precisely define N ("the" natural numbers) as the least inductive set.

How do you prove that you can't prove it, knowing the other axioms?  My question assumes you can prove it.  I don't want to use ZF, or any set theory for that matter.  I want to use FOL treating "is a natural number" as a predicate.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic is an example of a theory that incorporates the other axioms (successor, etc.) but does not include the induction schema.  It is known to be a weaker theory of arithmetic.

@leepappas - Even though ChatGPT cannot be trusted in general -- if you ask ChatGPT (free version) to clarify (1) what is meant by the least inductive set in ZF and (2) what is the relation between the concept of least inductive set and the principle of induction, it will also happen to give correct answers that may clarify your questions.

@leepappas: From this Math SE discussion, there's a model of the Peano axioms which doesn't satisfy induction. (Several of them, in fact!) If the other axioms proved induction, then all models would have it. I love the polynomial ring example: In N[x], the number x is neither even nor odd.

Your "proof" is bogus. Anytime you see "...", it cannot be a rigorous proof. Worse still, the fatal flaw in your proof is hidden inside that "...". If you wish to try to figure out the flaw yourself, try to write down a proof that does not have "...". If you fail, you will understand the flaw in your ideas better.
Secondly, there is no non-circular proof of induction (without using something at least as strong as induction).

And if your "proof" came from a book, throw that worthless book away.

It came from 'Symbolic Logic' by Irving M. Copi.  He gave it as a heuristic argument, he didn't intend for it to be rigorous.

@leepappas: I have heard of that book. Every single student I know who read that book came away with ridiculously severe misconceptions about logic. That kind of 'argument' is of exactly the same kind as "The bible is divinely inspired because it says so itself."; it is not a heuristic and it is utterly useless.

@leepappas - I don't know this book but took a quick look. I believe the author did not intend it as a heuristic argument for the validity of induction but as an informal explanation of what weak induction is (he writes: "... may be thought of as summarizing ...").  This is a bit sloppy, or potentially misleading, since it may suggest that we could actually perform infinitely many steps, but mathematical proofs can only actually consist of a finite number of steps. We use the principle of induction to prove theorems about infinite sets using only a finite number of steps in the proofs.

@mudskipper: It's worse than that. This horrible book calls "P(1) and P(2) and P(3) and..." (with the terrible ellipsis) a proposition! Books that cannot teach well should never be published.

@mudskipper: Observe how such a disgusting book has caused at least one reader (the asker) to produce an equally bogus poof in which the logically bogus "ellipsis" (of course) shows up.

@user21820 - I agree it's a sloppy presentation. When writing for absolute beginners authors should definitely be more careful.

Complete Induction is part of the definition of the set of natural numbers. (Note that some people include 0 in the natural numbers and some don’t).
The axiom is: If P(1) is true, and if for every natural number k, P(k) implies P(succ(k)), then P(n) is true for every natural number n.
Now take the statement P(k): k is a natural number. And take the set M = { 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 … }. The conditions of complete induction are met, but P(n) is not true for all elements of M. For example, 1.5 is not a natural number. Or take M’ = { -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, … }. Again P(-1) and P(0) are not true. But that’s ok because M and M’ are not N.
The important thing is: You are mixing up what you think the natural numbers are with how they are defined. Peano stated “this is an axiom. A set that is meeting all the axioms is called “natural numbers”.”  You on the other hand seem to think that there is a set of natural numbers for no reason other than that you think they should exist.
You didn’t prove anything about natural numbers. You compared your preconceptions with the axioms and they matched. But without peano’s axioms you have nothing.

The argument can be carried out fully in FOL, but it will then run afoul of Löwenheim-Skolem. When it comes to larger-than-finite collections, there's no avoiding building some sort of extensional property-aggregator which builds class-style collections, and we might as well use sets since they are the freeest approach. (You could also use vector spaces, as in the linked article, but you'll need to build the natural numbers first for scalars!)

Suppose your Axiomatic system for N consists of only the following three postulates:
P1. x ∈ N iff x=1 ∨ ∃y (x=y' ∧ y ∈ N)
P2. 0'=1 ∧ 0 ∉ N
P3. If x'=y' then x=y
Can you prove induction?
Theorem 1: 1 ∈ N

1 ∈ N iff 1=1 ∨ ∃y (1=y' ∧ y ∈ N) [P1]
1=1 [reflexivity of equality]
1=1 ∨ ∃y (1=y' ∧ y ∈ N) [2; addition]
1 ∈ N [3,1; MP2]

Q.E.D.
Theorem 1 is one of Peano's 5 axioms.
Theorem 2: ~∃y∈N[y'=1]

∃y∈N[y'=1] [OSC1]
Z'=1 ∧ z ∈N [1; EI]
0'=1 ∧ 0 ∉ N [P2]
Z'=0' [2,3; transitivity of equality]
If z'=0' then z=0 [P3]
Z=0 [4,5; MP]
0 ∈ N [2,6; substitution]
0 ∈ N ∧ 0 ∉ N [7,3; conjunction]
If ∃y∈N[y'=1] then contradiction [1-8; CSC1]
~∃y∈N[y'=1] [9; RAA]

Q E.D.
Theorem 2 is one of Peano's 5 axioms.
Theorem 3: ∀m[If m ∈N then m' ∈N]

n ∈N [OSC1]
n' ∈ N iff n'=1 ∨ ∃y (n'=y' ∧ y ∈ N)
n=x ∧ x ∈N [1; substitution]
n'=x' [3; successors are unique]
n'=x' ∧ x ∈N [4,3; conjunction]
∃y (n'=y' ∧ y ∈ N) [5; EG]
n'=1 ∨ ∃y (n'=y' ∧ y ∈ N) [6; addition]
n' ∈N [7,2; MP2]
If n ∈N then n' ∈N [1-8;CSC1]
∀m[If m ∈N then m' ∈N] [9; UG]

Q.E.D.
Theorem 3 is one of Peano's 5 axioms.
P3 is one of Peano's 5 axioms.  It states that a predecessor of a number is unique.
And, if x=y then x'=y' follows purely by the properties of equality.  It states that the successor of a number is unique.
So if 1' is a successor of 1, then 1' is the successor of 1.
By recursive uses of P1, we generate a sequence of true propositions.
1 ∈N, 1' ∈N, 1'' ∈N,...

Notice that
0'=1
0''=2
0'''=3
etc.
Thus, if you count the number of successor symbols, that is equivalent to the Arabic numeral.
Df. n = 0(n)
The existential part of P1 requires that y be instantiated by a specific natural number.  P1 only explicitly names 1 as denoting a specific natural number.   By recursion, the only other specific natural numbers, according to P1, are denoted by terms of the sequence: 0'',0''',...,0(n),...
Therefore,
n denotes an arbitrary natural number iff n = 0(n)
Theorem 4: Let P(m) be an arbitrary propositional function of m. If P(1) ∧ ∀m∈N[P(m) → P(m')] then ∀m∈N[P(m)]

P(1) ∧ ∀m∈N[P(m) → P(m')] [OSC1]
~∀m∈N[P(m)] [OSC2]
∃m∈N[~P(m)] [2; QN]
n ∈N ∧ ~P(n) [3; EI]
~P(n) [4; simplification 2]
n = 0(n) [Df]
~P(0(n)) [5,6; substitution]
P(0') [1; simplification 1]
If P(0') then P(0'') [1; UI]
P(0'') [8,9; MP X 1]
If P(0'') then P(0''') [1; UI]
P(0''') [10,11; MP X 2]
...
P(0(n)) [MP X n-1]
P(0(n)) ∧ ~P(0(n)) [13,7; conjunction]
If~∀m∈N[P(m)] then contradiction [2-14; CSC2]
∀m∈N[P(m)] [15; RAA]
If P(1) ∧ ∀m∈N[P(m) → P(m')] then ∀m∈N[P(m)] [1-16; CSC1]

Q.E.D.
Theorem 4 is weak mathematical induction.  Thus, mathematical induction is provable in this Axiomatic system for the natural numbers.
Thus, you can prove mathematical induction without the notion of set, using first order predicate logic.  Everywhere I used ∈ N, replace that with the predicate "denotes a natural number".
A system equivalent to Peano's system less induction is:
A1. If x=1 ∨ ∃y (x=y' ∧ y ∈ N) then x ∈N
A2. 0'=1 ∧ 0 ∉ N
A3. If x'=y' then x=y
IF you add to this the converse of A1, namely
A4. If x ∈N then x=1 ∨ ∃y (x=y' ∧ y ∈ N)
THEN you can prove induction.
A1 states
"x=1 ∨ ∃y (x=y' ∧ y ∈ N)" is a sufficient condition for x to denote a natural number.
A4 states that condition is necessary for x to denote a natural number.

When you use a recurisive construction on the Natural Numbers, how do you know it works for an arbitrary n? The answer, is that you are implicitly using the recursion theorem ( which uses Mathematical Induction), or you are proving a fact about the recursive construction- also by Mathematical Induction.

@MichaelCarey, axiom P1 gives the answer, and it doesn't use mathematical induction.  Let x denote an arbitrary natural number.  By P1, X=1 or there is a y such that x=y' and y is a natural number.  The principle of induction follows from the recursive definition.

Properties of recursively defined functions and sets can often be proved by an induction principle that follows  from the recursive definition. For example, the definition of the natural numbers presented here directly implies the principle of mathematical induction for natural numbers: if a property holds of the natural number 0 (or 1), and the property holds of n + 1 whenever it holds of n, then the property holds of all natural numbers (Aczel 1977:742).
